# Class 'Net_SSH2' not found in... when using phpseclib

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

I'm trying to use phpseclib to run a few ssh commands on my server. Attempting the below, I get `Class 'Net_SSH2' not found in....` which seems to indicate `phpseclib` is not properly loaded, yet the echo shows that the include is working.

What have I done wrong here?

#### My `php`

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

$thepath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/inc/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php';
echo '<strong>Full include path:</strong> '. $thepath;
include ($thepath); 


$included_files = get_included_files();

foreach ($included_files as $filename) {
     echo "<br><strong>Included file:</strong>$filename";
}


$ssh = new Net_SSH2('xx.xx.x.xx.x'); // server's ip address
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) { // filled in correctly 
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
Done.
```

#### The output

```
Full include path: /var/chroot/home/content/08/555555555/html/inc/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php
Included file:/home/content/08/555555555/html/TeamBoard/deploy.php
Included file:/home/content/08/555555555/html/inc/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php
Fatal error: Class 'Net_SSH2' not found in /home/content/08/555555555/html/TeamBoard/deploy.php on line 25
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On github.com there are two branches (in addition to the master branch) - 1.0 and 2.0. 2.0 is namespaced so to call that you'd need to do \phpseclib\Net\SSH2.

If you downloaded the zip file from phpseclib.sourceforge.net then you're running the 1.0 branch. If that's what you're running you'll need to update the include path. eg.

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
```

If you're running the 2.0 branch (or master branch) you'll need to use an auto loader. Example:

```
<?php
// https://raw.githubusercontent.com/composer/composer/master/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php

include('autoloader.php');

$loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
$loader->addPsr4('phpseclib\\', __DIR__.'/phpseclib');
$loader->register();

use \phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;

$rsa = new RSA();
```

Comment: @Tofandel - do feel free to make a pull request to their docs: https://github.com/phpseclib/docs Alternatively, sign up to assist with documentation @ https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/phpseclib/commit